# How do DHT's handle node failure

Tags: blockchain, dht

So my understanding in a DHT is that all of the data is split up among a bunch of different nodes. If we wanted to run computation using some subset of this data, but this data was stored on a node that has gone offline, does the computation fail. I'd like a high level explanation of how the data from node A is maintained in the DHT after node A goes offline or fails. Thanks.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, so off-topic here. See instead SoftwareEngineering maybe.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Feel free to draft a better message for the requester and vote as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to data when a node dies in a DHT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009535/what-happens-to-data-when-a-node-dies-in-a-dht)